# How convert folder of images to csv to trine model

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, image-classification

I am new to machine learning. I found a disaster images dataset on kaggle , but it does not have a CSV file extension. The dataset is a group of folders classified according to the type of disaster, so how do I deal with it to train a model

Comment: If you use Tensorflow or Keras library, that kind of structure is even more favorable. Just take your time on learning the Tensorflow's `ImageDataGenerator` and `flow_from_directory()` documentations.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.